# CSS Different color foreach accordion title

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a *bootstrap* accordion and I would like to change the color of the `h4` title for each of the elements in the *DOM* up to 4 elements then repeating the previous colors.

```css
.my-platform-title:nth-child(2n+1) {
    color: #1a9e49;
}
.my-platform-title:nth-child(2n) {
    color: #7bc9c8 !important;
}
.my-platform-title:nth-child(3n) {
    color: #fd8d6e !important;
}
.my-platform-title:nth-child(4n) {
    color: #bf6da6 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-heading my-panel-heading" role="tab" id="platform1">
    <h4 class="panel-title my-panel-title my-platform-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#platforms" href="#platform-collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="platform-collapse1">
            <span class="fa fa-plus-square-o text-success"></span> Platform 1
        </a>
    </h4>
</div>
<div class="panel-heading my-panel-heading" role="tab" id="platform<2">
    <h4 class="panel-title my-panel-title my-platform-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#platforms" href="#platform-collapse<2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="platform-collapse<2">
            <span class="fa fa-plus-square-o text-success"></span> Platform 2
        </a>
    </h4>
</div>
<div class="panel-heading my-panel-heading" role="tab" id="platform3">
    <h4 class="panel-title my-panel-title my-platform-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#platforms" href="#platform-collapse3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="platform-collapse3">
            <span class="fa fa-plus-square-o text-success"></span> Platform 3
        </a>
    </h4>
</div>
<div class="panel-heading my-panel-heading" role="tab" id="platform4">
    <h4 class="panel-title my-panel-title my-platform-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#platforms" href="#platform-collapse4" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="platform-collapse4">
            <span class="fa fa-plus-square-o text-success"></span> Platform 4
        </a>
    </h4>
</div>
```

What is happening is that the first color applies and the others are ignored.

Comment: Show the HTML structure including the parent element, and possible siblings.

Comment: When you use !important, it overrides the cascade, remove it.

Comment: I tried that code in a snippet and it worked. Dunno what's wrong here.

Comment: check this out : http://nthmaster.com/

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your selectors are wrong. I mean they could serve you in this very case, but in general `2n+1` means every odd child, `3n` means every third child and so on.

Instead you should write plain simple numbers: :nth-child(1) - selects the first child,...

If this is not working, for whatever reason, and considering that you only want to change the color, I suggest you to use more friendly and clear approach adding custom classes for the colors, like this:

```css
.color-green {
    color: #1a9e49;
}

.color-turquoise {
    color: #7bc9c8 !important;
}

.color-orange {
    color: #fd8d6e !important;
}

.color-purple {
    color: #bf6da6 !important;
}
```

```html
<h4 class="panel-title my-panel-title my-platform-title color-green">Title 1</h4>
<h4 class="panel-title my-panel-title my-platform-title color-turquoise">Title 2</h4>
<h4 class="panel-title my-panel-title my-platform-title color-orange">Title 3</h4>
<h4 class="panel-title my-panel-title my-platform-title color-purple">Title 4</h4>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion however I am outputting the HTML using a PHP foreach, so I would really like to just use CSS to achieve this rather than adding more markup

Answer (score 2):

`nth-child` is an element selector so it would be the child in comparison to the parent - in your case the `h4.my-platform-title` is always the first child of the div.

what you need to do is move the nth-child onto the parent div (if they are the only children of their parent - in example below, I have added a container around your headings).

You also need to colour the anchor rather than the h4

```css
.panel-heading:nth-child(1n) .my-platform-title a {
  color: #1a9e49;
}
.panel-heading:nth-child(2n) .my-platform-title a {
  color: #7bc9c8;
}
.panel-heading:nth-child(3n) .my-platform-title a {
  color: #fd8d6e;
}
.panel-heading:nth-child(4n) .my-platform-title a {
  color: #bf6da6;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-heading my-panel-heading" role="tab" id="platform1">
    <h4 class="panel-title my-panel-title my-platform-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#platforms" href="#platform-collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="platform-collapse1">
            <span class="fa fa-plus-square-o text-success"></span> Platform 1
        </a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-heading my-panel-heading" role="tab" id="platform2">
    <h4 class="panel-title my-panel-title my-platform-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#platforms" href="#platform-collapse2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="platform-collapse2">
            <span class="fa fa-plus-square-o text-success"></span> Platform 2
        </a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-heading my-panel-heading" role="tab" id="platform3">
    <h4 class="panel-title my-panel-title my-platform-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#platforms" href="#platform-collapse3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="platform-collapse3">
            <span class="fa fa-plus-square-o text-success"></span> Platform 3
        </a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-heading my-panel-heading" role="tab" id="platform4">
    <h4 class="panel-title my-panel-title my-platform-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#platforms" href="#platform-collapse4" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="platform-collapse4">
            <span class="fa fa-plus-square-o text-success"></span> Platform 4
        </a>
    </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whilst the snippet is working here, it is not working in the main code for some reason and the full code is way to much to output in the question

Comment: @JustinErswell, are your headers the only children of their parent element? Can you create a jsfiddle with the full accordion structure (you can delete any content - I just want to see where the headers sit)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to define different additional classes for each header like this and then to style the classes individually:

```
<h4 class="panel-title my-panel-title my-platform-title my-platform-title-1">Title 1</h4>
<h4 class="panel-title my-panel-title my-platform-title my-platform-title-2">Title 2</h4>
<h4 class="panel-title my-panel-title my-platform-title my-platform-title-3">Title 3</h4>
<h4 class="panel-title my-panel-title my-platform-title my-platform-title-4">Title 4</h4>
```

Comment: That's not the answer to this question. The questions was to use css pseudo classes to assign color.

Comment: Thanks for the 2 helpful comments. Yes it's true that I am new here but probably I will never downgrade other users answers. I have posted a new answer and hope that you will like this one more ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want to style the link colors and not the titles themselves:

```
.my-panel-heading:nth-child(1) a {
    color: #1a9e49;
}
.my-panel-heading:nth-child(2) a {
    color: #7bc9c8;
}
.my-panel-heading:nth-child(3) a {
    color: #fd8d6e;
}
.my-panel-heading:nth-child(4) a {
    color: #bf6da6;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4jc7vr9r/1/